# How to enable Trigger programmatically on Google script

Tags: google-apps-script

The following code is creating trigger:

```
var trigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger("function_name")
.timeBased()
  .everyMinutes(5)
  .create();
```

but they are getting disabled automatically due to some issue in V8 engine

Ref: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150756612

Disabling V8 is having critical side effects as old ES5 couldn't support all the other functions

So, is there any way to enable the disabled trigger programmatically?

Comment: am not sure why this question was rated down!! this is a genuine question as I need to intervene manually (to enable the trigger) every day as the triggered created exists in disable.. am sure many might have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

From the question:

> So, is there any way to enable the disabled trigger programmatically?

There isn't.

The alternative is to use Babel or something like that that could make your code work on the old Google Apps Script runtime (Mozilla Rhino)

Reference

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger

Comment: switching to the old runtime script is disabling few core features of the GS code.. so, I was manually enabling the trigger for the past year daily. didn't find a solution to automate it

Comment: @RaviG The issue referred in your question is still open. It has been starred by 118 users, it has 6 duplicates... The SO that is referred in the issue has only one answer, pointing back to the issue.